# A question on surface integral on how to take projections

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals, multiple-integral, iterated-integrals

> While evaluating $$\int\int_S (x^2+y^2)z \ dS$$ where $S$ is the surface of hemisphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=4, z\ge 0$, they have used the formula $$\int\int_S \phi(x,y,z) \ dS = \int\int_D\phi(x,y,f(x,y)) \sqrt{1+f_x^2+f_y^2} \ dA$$, where $D$ is projection of $S$ on $x-y$ plane.

My question is what we had done if $S$ was a surface of a **SPHERE** instead of hemisphere?

Do we need to take projection on $x-y$ plane as we had done in case of hemisphere and then double the answer or we have to take the projection on some another plane?

Please help me to understand this. Thanks

Comment: When only upper part is given we can write z explicitly in terms of x and y but when whole sphere is taken I think we need to parametrize sphere ( $theta$, $phi$) and apply second version of formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is easiest to get your head around it if you break the region in two.

we have the hemisphere above the plane,

$S_1: z = \sqrt {4-x^2 - y^2}$

and the hemisphere below the plane

$S_2: z = -\sqrt {4-x^2 - y^2}$

$\iint f(x,y,z)\ dS_1 + \iint f(x,y,z) \ dS_2$

$\|dS_1\| = \|-z_x, -z_y, 1\| = \sqrt {4x^2 + 4y^2 + 1} \ dx\ dy$

$\|dS_2\| = \|z_x, z_y, -1\| = \sqrt {4x^2 + 4y^2 + 1} \ dx\ dy$

We want to keep the vectors pointing out, hence the sign change.

but $\|dS_1\| =\|dS_2\| $ it is the same for both hemispheres, so we can add the functions together.

$\iint [f(x,y,\sqrt {4-x^2 - y^2}) + f(x,y,-\sqrt {4-x^2 - y^2})]\sqrt {4-x^2 - y^2}\ dx\ dy$

and in this case

$f(x,y,z) + f(x,y,-z) = 0$

Update

converting to Spherical coordinates

$x = 2 \cos \theta\sin\phi\\
y = 2 \sin\theta\sin\phi\\
z = 2 \cos \phi$

$\|dS\| = \|(\frac {dx}{d\theta}, \frac {dy}{d\theta},\frac {dz}{d\theta})\times(\frac {dx}{d\phi}, \frac {dy}{d\phi},\frac {dz}{d\phi})\|\ d\theta\ d\phi = 4\sin\phi \ d\theta\ d\phi$

over the hemisphere:

$\int_0^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{\frac \pi2} (4cos^2\theta \sin^2\phi + 4\sin^2\theta\sin^2\phi)(2\cos \phi) (4\sin\phi) \ d\theta\ d\phi\\ 
\int_0^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{\frac {\pi}{2}} 32\sin^3\phi\cos \phi \ d\theta\ d\phi$

over the sphere

$\int_0^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi} 32\sin^3\phi\cos \phi \ d\theta\ d\phi$

Comment: @AnuragJain Thanks, I had a few things to clean up.  I think I have it correct now.

Comment: can we take the projection on any other plane?

Comment: sure you could say $y = \sqrt {4-x^2 - z^2}, dS = (-y_x, 1, -z_x) \ dx \ dz, \|dS\| = \sqrt {y_x^2 + y_z^2 + 1}\ dx\ dz$

Comment: And in that case, we do not need to break the region in two surfaces, right?

Comment: With the parmaterization, I just gave, you still would.  If you converted to spherical coordinates you wouldn't have to break up the integral.

Comment: Oh yeah, got it. It will still be the same case.

Comment: How to do it using spherical coordinates? I have not seen surface integrals using spherical coordinates.

Comment: I have put in an update using spherical coordinates